# Application with embedded LuaJIT fails with Valgrind

Tags: ubuntu, lua, cmake, valgrind, luajit

I've been facing problems trying to instantiate the LuaJIT's Lua State:

```
lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
```

When running the application normally, or even on debugging I have no problems whatsoever. It runs just fine. But when I run the same app with Valgrind Memory Analysis, `L` will always return a solid `nullptr` and then the application will crash.

I have searched a lot on Google about it. I have some clues that LuaJIT does not use System's malloc and, for some reason related to that, it fails to allocate memory under Valgrind.

My environment is Linux x64 (Ubuntu 14.04), GCC 4.8.2, LuaJIT 5.1 and CMake 3.0.

Comment: Have you built with [`LUAJIT_USE_VALGRIND`](http://repo.or.cz/w/luajit-2.0.git/blob/dfa173b92962350ac5f019dd4a340ad1c5c265c7:/src/Makefile#l131) defined?

Comment: You mean my application or the lib itself?

Comment: I don't think the problem is luajit specific anymore. I have removed LuaJIT and tried with plain LUA. Same problem...

Comment: I tried compiling LuaJIT with LUAJIT_USE_VALGRIND. Same problem too.

Comment: Does the application run correctly if you `export MALLOC_CHECK_=2` before running it (without valgrind)? Because what this sounds like is some sort of memory corruption/etc. issue that valgrind (by not using the normal allocator) is exposing). You aren't using a custom lua allocator function are you?